# Matplotlib 3.0 with osx backend

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, ipython, conda

I installed Python 3.7 on macOS 10.14 using Miniconda from [here](https://conda.io/miniconda.html). My workflow uses iPython to run scripts that generate plots with Matplotlib. In my iPython configuration file `ipython_config.py`, I have the following settings to properly render figure windows on the Mac:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.gui = 'osx'
c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = 'osx'
```

When I run iPython in the terminal, the following error appears:

> ImportError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X
>   backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not
>   installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more
>   information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please
>   either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other
>   backends. If you are using (Ana)Conda please install python.app and
>   replace the use of 'python' with 'pythonw'. See 'Working with
>   Matplotlib on OSX' in the Matplotlib FAQ for more information.

I did not receive this error when using Matplotlib 2.2.3.

The Matplotlib 3.0 [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/faq/osx_framework.html#osxframework-faq) states that a framework build of Python (referred to as `pythonw`) is needed when using Conda and Matplotlib. I installed this with `conda install python.app`. The documentation then says to use `pythonw` instead of `python`. But how do I tell iPython to use `pythonw`?

Comment: I am having the same problem. This seems to be a long-standing, unresolved issue of anaconda on OSX ([github issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/199)). I am at the same point as you are.

Comment: Try `pythonw -m ipython`

Comment: @shadowtalker that does not work.. it just says 'no module named ipython' even from a conda env where IPython is verifiably actually installed. For whatever reason, pythonw (installed as python.app via conda) cannot locate IPython.

Answer (score 4):

Typing

```
echo "backend: TkAgg" > ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc
```

in a terminal fixed IPython for me.

Comment: That is just using a different backend, which doesn't appear to answer the question